# How do I remove Label text in Django generated form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form that is displaying well only for the label text that I don't want and I have tried all I could to let it off my form but it won't just go...

**forms.py**:

```
class sign_up_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields =['email']
        widgets = {
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={
                'id': 'email',
                'class': 'form-control input-lg emailAddress',
                'name': 'email',
                'placeholder': 'Enter a valid email'})}
```

I have tried:
**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from mysite.forms import sign_up_form

def register(request):
    sign_up = sign_up_form(auto_id=False)
    context = {'sign_up_form': sign_up}
    return render(request, 'mysite/register.html', context)
```

I need my `widgets` as defined above.

Comment: How exactly are you rendering the form?

Comment: Did you try adding `label: ''` to `attrs`?

Answer (score 39):

In ModelForms there will be default labels so you have to over-ride where you don't need labels

you can define it like this

```
class sign_up_form(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label='')
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields =['email']
```

This method will not include labels for your form, other method depends on rendering in template. You can always avoid labels from form
`<label>MY LABEL</label>` instead of `{{ form.field.label }}`

Answer (score 11):

In `__init__` method set your field label as empty.This will remove label text.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(sign_up_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].label = ""
```

Comment: It is giving empty space..

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting to remove all labels, you can use:

```
class sign_up_form(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for key, field in self.fields.items():
            field.label = ""
```

Comment: or `for field in self.field.values()`